# About definition of interior, boundary and closure

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, definition

> Find the interior, boundary and closure of $[0,1]∪{r∈[1,2]:r∉Q}$

---

What I did so far:

Let $S=[0,1]∪{r∈[1,2]:r∉\mathbb{Q}}$

Then i checked the definitions $\dots$

> Def open ball
>
> $B(a;r)=\{x∈R^n:|x−a|<r\}$.
>
> Def interior
>
> $S^{\circ}=\{x∈R^n:∃ε>0:B(x;ε)⊆S\}.$
>
> Def boundary
>
> $∂S=\{x∈R^n:∀ε>0:B(x;ε)∩S≠\varnothing  \wedge  B(x;ε)∩S^c≠\varnothing\}$.
>
> Def closure
>
> $\overline{S}=\{{x∈R^n:∀ε>0,B(x;ε)∩S≠\varnothing}\}$.

Looks like an open ball in $\mathbb{R^1}$ is just the set of all the points on some open line segment, or some open interval on $\mathbb{R}$, if some point in $S^{\circ}$ then we can draw a ball with positive radius that this ball is also in $S$, that can conclude:
$$S^{\circ}=(0,1)$$

And I try to understand the defination of that so called boundary: If some point in $∂S$ then all the balls centred at this point with positive radius must have non-empty intersection with both $S$ and $S^c$. Therefore I guess $0$ must in $∂S$, also $r\in[1,2]:r\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ in $∂S$.

$$∂S=\{0\}\cup[1,2]\backslash\mathbb{Q}$$

Finally, if a point is in the closure, that means all the balls centred at this point with positive radius must have non-empty intersection with $S$, since $S^{\circ}$ and $∂S$ both have intersection with $S$, that should have $S^{\circ}\cup ∂S\subseteq \overline S$, and any point in $S$ is either in it's boundary or in it's interior, that implies $\overline S\subseteq S^{\circ}\cup ∂S$, therefore:
$$\overline S = S^{\circ}\cup ∂S$$

---

Is my understanding to the definitions correct?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is one snag here: you have to know whether these are the interior/boundary/closure of $S$ *in itself* or in $\mathbb{R}$. They are not the same. Most likely you want to take the operations in $\mathbb{R}$, which will mean that the closure and boundary may contain points which aren't actually in $S$ (and will, in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=[0, 1]\cup r$ such that $r\in [1, 2]\cap \mathbb{Q}^{c}$, then

1. $S^{\circ}=(0, 1)$
2. $∂S= \{0\}\cup[1, 2]$
   because if $r\in [1, 2] $ then for all $\epsilon >0$, $B(r, \epsilon)\cap S$ and $B(r, \epsilon)\cap S^{c}$ are nonempty set
3. $\bar{S}=S^{\circ}\cup ∂S$.